# dropdown as in intel website

Tags: jquery, html, css

I made a mega drop down now i want its styling as in intel.com, i mean the arrows that are coming below the links, how to achieve that, my code is below.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <style>
    #header {
        border: 10px;
        border-color: #000000;

    }
   div.inline{float:left; width: 18%;}
   .cls{clear:both;}
  content_div div{ margin-right:10%; height:150px; border-color: #008AD2;}
   </style>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script>

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#sub_menu').hide();
                $('#menu').hover(function(){
                     $('#sub_menu').show();
                },function(){
                    $('#sub_menu').hide();
                });

                $('#sub_menu').hover(function(){
                     $('#sub_menu').show();
                },function(){
                    $('#sub_menu').hide();
                });
              $('#content_div div').hide();
              $('#content_div div:first').show();

               $('.inline').hover(function(){
                   var id=$(this).attr("id");
                  // alert($(this).attr("id"));
                     $('#content_div div').hide();
                     if(id=="1")
                         {
                             $('#one').show();
                         }
                         else if(id=="2")
                             {
                                 $('#two').show();
                             }
                              else if(id=="3")
                             {
                                 $('#three').show();
                             }
                          else if(id=="4")
                             {
                                 $('#four').show();
                             }
                              else if(id=="5")
                             {
                                 $('#five').show();
                             }
                },function(){
                 //   $('#content_div div').hide();
             // $('#content_div div:first').show();
                });
 });
        </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="header" style="background-color:#008AD2; border-color: #000000">
            <br/><br/>
            <div id="menu" style="background-color:#ffffff;width:20%;margin-left:10px"> keep a image for menu drop down </div>
            <div style="background-color:#ffffff;float:right; margin-right:20px;"> sign img</div>
        </div>

        <div id="sub_menu" class="sub_menu" style="margin-right:10%;margin-right: 10px;border:2px solid #000000;">
            <div>
            <div id="1" class="inline">menu list here1 </div>
            <div id="2" class="inline">menu list here 2</div>
            <div id="3" class="inline">menu list here 3</div>
            <div id="4" class="inline">menu list here 4</div>
            <div id="5" class="inline">menu list here 5</div>
            <br class="cls"/>
            </div>
            <div id="content_div">
            <div id="one" class="content" style="height:100px; background-color: #000000"> below list1
            </div>  
             <div id="two"class="content" style="height:150px; background-color: #0000ff"> below list2
            </div>  
             <div id="three" class="content" style="height:180px; background-color: #0ff000"> below list3
            </div>  
             <div id="four" class="content" style="height:200px; background-color: #00ff00"> below list4
            </div>  
             <div id="five" class="content" style="height:100px; background-color: #ff0000"> below list5
            </div>  
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So what I require is just styling the functioning have been achieved.

Thanks

Comment: set the border image to one with the arrow on hover?

Comment: Using any browser debugger tool (default key usually F12) you can investigate the styles applied to the elements in the DOM. In Chrome for example you can right-click and select "Inspect Element", that opens the debugger tool on that element. Then you can see all the CSS applied to that element and it even shows you the file name the applied style is in. The just go download the CSS and play around with it.

Comment: but its very big css file and also m unable to get the particular css with fire bug